# Problem about the Galois group elements in Sage

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

I am computing a Galois group as below in Sage.

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^4-2)
L = K.galois_closure('b')
G=L.galois_group()
```

Here, $G=\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q)} \simeq D_4$ where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ and$D_4$ is generated by rotation and reflections as it is the symmetry group of the square.

However, Sage returns the elements as below:

```
()
(1,2,8,7)(3,4,6,5)
(1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8)
(1,4)(2,3)(5,8)(6,7)
(1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8)
(1,6)(2,4)(3,8)(5,7)
(1,7,8,2)(3,5,6,4)
(1,8)(2,7)(3,6)(4,5)
```

Also,

```
G.gens()
```

returns

```
 [(1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8), (1,7,8,2)(3,5,6,4)]
```

and I can see that the output $(1,7,8,2)(3,5,6,4)$ is $r =(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8)$ is $s = (14)(23)$.

How can I relate these two permutations?

*P.s. I could not find anything about the labeling in the reference.*

*Edit*. My question is extended as follows. As it was mentioned in the comments,

```
G.is_isomorphic(DihedralGroup(4))
```

returns true.

Now, I named the generators of $G$ and $D_4$ as $gr,gr$ and $dr,ds$ respectively:

```
dr = DihedralGroup(4).gens()[0]
ds = DihedralGroup(4).gens()[1]
print dr
print ds
```

returns

```
(1,2,3,4)
(1,4)(2,3)
```

and

```
gr = G.gens()[1]
gs = G.gens()[0]
print gs
print gr
```

returns

```
(1,2)(3,5)(4,6)(7,8)
(1,5,8,4)(2,6,7,3).
```

Next, I look for the Artin symbol $\sigma = \text{Fr}_{\mathfrak{p}}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ for primes above $3$. I expect to get $rs$ or $r3s$ as if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $i^p \equiv -1 \pmod {p}$.

Thus, for $p=3 $, we have $$\sigma = \text{Fr}_{\mathfrak{p}} (K / \mathbb{Q}) = i^p \equiv -i \pmod p \iff \sigma = rs \text{ or } r^3 s$$
as  $(rs)(i)=-i$ and $(r^3s)(i)=-i$.

However,

```
{G.artin_symbol(P) for P in L.primes_above(3)}
```

returns

```
{(1,2)(3,5)(4,6)(7,8), (1,7)(2,8)(3,4)(5,6)}
```

meanwhile, the output of $gr*gs$ and $gr^3 * gs$ is as below:

```
gr*gs = (1,3)(2,4)(5,7)(6,8)
gr^3*gs =(1,6)(2,5)(3,8)(4,7)
```

So, what is the problem that I am missing?

Comment: If I understand well your question, you are seeking a correspondance between the answer given by SAGE (as permutations of 8 symbols) and the classical representation of $D_4$ as permutations of 4 symbols. I advise you check the same relations, i.e. $r^4=1$, $s^2=1$ and $s.r=r^3.s$. One it is verified, you can conclude that there is an isomorphism between both groups, that does send one representation of $r$ to the other and one representation of $s$ to the other.

Comment: Do you know that there exists a Sage function testing the isomorphism of two groups : G.is_isomorphic(DihedralGroup(4)) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes I found out some. time later asking the question. I have few more questions now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with the code:

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^4-2)
L.<b> = K.galois_closure()
G = L.galois_group()
```

The elements of the Galois group correspond to permutations of the roots of the minimal polynomial of $b$. To get this information, just ask `?G` in the ipython-sage-interpreter:

```
sage: ?G

Type:           GaloisGroup_v2_with_category
String form:    Galois group 8T4 ([4]2) with order 8 of x^8 + 28*x^4 + 2500
Length:         8
File:           /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sage/rings/number_field/galois_group.py
Docstring:
   The Galois group of an (absolute) number field.

   Note:

     We define the Galois group of a non-normal field K to be the
     Galois group of its Galois closure L, and elements are stored as
     permutations of the roots of the defining polynomial of L, *not*
     as permutations of the roots (in L) of the defining polynomial of
     K. The latter would probably be preferable, but is harder to
     implement. Thus the permutation group that is returned is always
     simply-transitive.The 'arithmetical' features (decomposition and
     ramification groups, Artin symbols etc) are only available for
     Galois fields.

   EXAMPLES:

..............................................................
```

So which is the minimal polynomial of $b$?

```
sage: b.minpoly()
x^8 + 28*x^4 + 2500

sage: b.complex_embedding()
-2.37841423000544 - 1.18920711500272*I
```

Well, this makes me angry already, what a bad choice!
I would really want to have an $i$ and an element
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad A=\sqrt[4]2\qquad}$$
in $L$ (since $a$ is already given as an element in $K$),
but now i am getting a weird $b$ from sage.

- What could $A$ (real, positive root of $x^4=2$) be in terms of $b$?

  ```
    sage: for r in (X^4 - 2).roots(multiplicities=False):
    ....:     print(f"{r}  with complex embedding {r.complex_embedding()}")
    ....: 
    1/120*b^5 + 19/60*b  with complex embedding -1.66533453693773e-16 - 1.18920711500272*I
    1/240*b^5 - 41/120*b  with complex embedding 1.18920711500272 + 1.66533453693773E-16*I
    -1/240*b^5 + 41/120*b  with complex embedding -1.18920711500272 - 1.66533453693773E-16*I
    -1/120*b^5 - 19/60*b  with complex embedding 1.66533453693773e-16 + 1.18920711500272*I
  ```
- What could $i$ be in terms of $b$?

  ```
    sage: for r in (X^4 - 1).roots(multiplicities=False):
    ....:     print(f"{r}  with complex embedding {r.complex_embedding()}")
    ....: 
    1  with complex embedding 1.00000000000000
    -1  with complex embedding -1.00000000000000
    1/48*b^4 + 7/24  with complex embedding 1.11022302462516e-16 + 1.00000000000000*I
    -1/48*b^4 - 7/24  with complex embedding -1.11022302462516e-16 - 1.00000000000000*I
  ```

In order the arrange an answer, i will work in sage on the $b$-world, this means inside of `L`, but all the structure will suffer translations into the world of $K(i)=\Bbb Q(a,i)$. Instead of $i$ there is a `j` in code, think of it as an element in $L$ that maps to $i$ in $K(i)$.
So we work with $b$ "algebraically", and look what happens with Galois morphisms when applied on:
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
A  &:= \frac1{240}(b^5 - 82b)\in L\ ,\\
j  &:= \frac1{48}(b^4 + 14)\in L\ .
\end{aligned}
\qquad}
$$
Let us ask for the action of each element of $G$ on these elements:

```
A = (b^5 - 82*b) / 240
j = (b^4 + 14) / 48

for g in G:
   ku = [k for k in [0, 1, 2, 3] if g(A)/A == j^k][0]
   kj = [k for k in [0, 1, 2, 3] if g(j)   == j^k][0]
   print(f"g = {str(g):20} :: gj = j^{kj} and gA = A j^{ku}")
```

And we get the information:

```
g = ()                   :: gj = j^1 and gA = A j^0
g = (1,2,8,7)(3,4,6,5)   :: gj = j^1 and gA = A j^3
g = (1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8) :: gj = j^3 and gA = A j^1
g = (1,4)(2,3)(5,8)(6,7) :: gj = j^3 and gA = A j^2
g = (1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8) :: gj = j^3 and gA = A j^0
g = (1,6)(2,4)(3,8)(5,7) :: gj = j^3 and gA = A j^3
g = (1,7,8,2)(3,5,6,4)   :: gj = j^1 and gA = A j^1
g = (1,8)(2,7)(3,6)(4,5) :: gj = j^1 and gA = A j^2
```

So the element that invariates $j$ and sends $A$ to $Aj$ is
$(1782)(3564)$, corresponding to a rotation $R$ in a a dihedral group.
The element that invariates $A$, and maps $j\to -j$ is the "Spiegelung" $S$, given by $(15)(26)(37)(48)$ (and now at least we have a good labelling).

The morphism to the dihedral group is:

```
sage: D4 = DihedralGroup(4)
sage: D4.order()
8
sage: D4.gens()
((1,2,3,4), (1,4)(2,3))
sage: r, s = D4.gens()

sage: R = G( [(1,7,8,2), (3,5,6,4)] )
sage: S = G( [(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)] )
sage: G.gens()
[(1,2,8,7)(3,4,6,5), (1,6)(2,4)(3,8)(5,7), (1,8)(2,7)(3,6)(4,5)]
sage: g0, g1, g2 = G.gens()
sage: g0, g1, g2 = G.gens()

sage: g0 == R^3
True
sage: g1 == R^3*S
True
sage: g2 == R^2
True

sage: F = Hom(G, D4)((r^3, r^3*s, r^2))
```

Now we have a morphism to $D_4$ from $G$ in its ugly implementation as permutation group of $b$ and Co(njugates).

This gives the images in $D_4$ of the wanted Artin-symbols for the four primes above $3$ in $L$:

```
sage: [F( G.artin_symbol(P) ) for P in L.primes_above(3)]
[(1,3), (1,3), (2,4), (2,4)]
sage: r*s
(1,3)
sage: r^3*s
(2,4)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the effort and the great explanation. Now, can I say that "I cannot trust sage to get the "correct" Artin symbols, then?